# Use quaternions/remove gimbal lock from blender view

Tags: interface, 3d-view

This took me a while to find so I'm adding it here.

I was trying to use the `Project From View` `UV Unwrap` and because 1. there's no way to roll the view camera and 2. the camera gimbal locks at the poles I was having a lot of trouble getting the correct direction to match my texture.

The answer is of course to put the camera in quaternion mode, but I had no idea how to achieve this. There's the `Transform Orientation` selection box which has the `Gimbal` option but this is not for the camera's transform.

Answer (score 4):

What I wanted was to change the [**TrackBall/Turntable**](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Navigating/3D_View#TrackBall.2FTurntable) option in **`File->Preferences->Input`**

[image]
<sub>(source: [blender.org](https://wiki.blender.org/uploads/2/28/Manual-Part-I-Interface-Navigating-InfoWindow-ViewRotation2.5.png))</sub>

Also see:

- [What is the difference between the trackball and turntable style view modes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/657/what-is-the-difference-between-the-trackball-and-turntable-style-view-modes)

Comment: This script may also help add a bit of control to either view type: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/roll_view

Answer (score 0):

I found that under the TrackBall/Turntable option in File->Preferences->Input I changing "View Navigation" from "Walk" to "Fly" worked.