# How to rotate (roll) the 3D view like I'm tilting my head?

Tags: 3d-view

How would I rotate the view port along the axis from my forehead to the monitor, like as if I was tilting my head (but more like tilting the viewport)

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15049/how-to-roll-the-viewport ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you'd like to avoid viewport rotation lock around Z axis and to have possibility to rotate freely with <kbd>RMB</kbd>.

**Option 1 - switch to *Trackball* rotating method**

By default, Blender uses [Turntable rotation method](https://www.blender.org/manual/preferences/input.html#view-manipulation) for manipulating view. It means the rotation in 3D Viewport will be locked to Z axis. See [what the difference between *Trackball* and *Turntable* orbit styles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/657/what-is-the-difference-between-the-trackball-and-turntable-style-view-modes).

To change that in *File* > *User Preferences* (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>) choose **Input** page and find *Orbit Style* part.

[image: orbit style selection image]

After toggling it to **Trackball** the 3D Viewport will rotate freely.

[image: orbit style - trackball GIF]

**Option 2 - use View Roll**

Without changing anything in preferences it's possible to roll the view to change its angle. Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and rotate the mouse wheel
(or by using the key shortcuts <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Pad4</kbd>  / <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Pad6</kbd>) to rotate left / right:

[image: orbit style - roll view]

Comment: I managed to type "rotate with `RMB`" which is not what I wanted to type. It should be `MMB`.

Comment: @ideasman42 thanks, I see I included one more typo there. I thought to write about Trackball when writing Turntable. Thanks for the shortcuts also, it seems I couldn't find them in UI for to include appropriate entry

Comment: Neither of these work.

Comment: It is still working just fine in 2.8-2.9. If you fail to find the way through 2.9 UI with 2.7 instructions look up descriptions on how it works exactly in your version, even though internally Blender hasn't changed much